# enable google map

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, google-api, google-maps-api-2

Ii have a webpage which has a map control from:

(http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24468/Google-Maps-Control-for-ASP-NET-Part-1)

When I run it from `http://localhost` it executes fine. When I move it to my actual website, the page goes blank. Is this only for testing on localhost or is there anything else I'm missing. Can anybody guess what the problem is?

Is there any other way to have maps running

I am using VS2k8

Answer (score 2):

For v2 of the Google maps API, which the code in `GoogleMapControl.zip` uses, Google doesn't check the API key when running on localhost but they do when running elsewhere. Make sure that you have a [valid API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/signup) from Google and add it to the Web.config:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="GoogleAPIKey" value=""/>
  </appSettings>
```

There is a comment at the top of `Page_Load()` in `SimpleMapWithNoBubble.aspx.cs` that documents this.

Regarding the version of the API, in `cGoogleMap.cs`:

```
string _apiversion = "2";
```

I didn't dig any further to see if the code is written well enough that you could just change to v3 but it's worth a quick try.

As noted at the valid API key link above and in the comments below, v2 of the API is officially depreciated and it's scheduled to go away no later than [April 20, 2015](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_4_4).

Comment: yes i do have. but im clueless of this sample,  so i guess i need to add it here public static bool GeocodeAddress(GooglePoint GP,string GoogleAPIKey)
    {
        string sURL = "http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=" + GP.Address + "&output=xml&key=" + GoogleAPIKey;  .....

Comment: @Alkini, yes ur guess is rit .. but same result dude :(  is ther any sample to add the map in my asp webpage, which ur aware...

Comment: I can't remember if SO notifies you when I edit an answer, but I just changed it to point out that the API key belongs in Web.config.

Comment: @Alkini , yes u made a point "web.config" thats rit man...got WORKINGGGGG

Comment: Glad it's working. Perhaps you'd consider accepting the answer?

Comment: v2 of the Google Maps API was deprecated May 19, 2010.  From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference): "The Google Maps JavaScript API Version 2 has been officially deprecated as of May 19, 2010. The V2 API will continue to work until May 19, 2013. We encourage you to migrate your code to version 3 of the Maps JavaScript API."  New development that uses v2 is not recommended.

Comment: @geocodezip means i can go with the same sample with version 3 rit? and is the key required...

Comment: No.  It means don't waste your time developing in v2.  V3 is fairly different from v2 (similar, but different enough that code for v2 will most likely not work with v3).  Keys are not required for v3, but are recommended for usage tracking.

Comment: @geocodezip thanx , im fairly new to this maps, apis, and all, is ther a way(other than the above sample app) to enable(ver 3) on asp.net website and likewise launch it on my web...